Semantic versioning and the experimental API element
I version my APIs (of various types: REST, Java, etc.) according to the rules of semantic versioning (for REST API specifying the version in the OAS in the version field of the Info Object; for Java API, this is the version attribute of the corresponding artifact - the part of groupId, artifactId, version).
Currently, I want to introduce the practice of marking some API elements as experimental (for REST API, use a custom extension; for Java API, use a custom annotation).
Now, I can't understand how I should proceed with the API version in case of deleting the experimental element?

Case:

Adding an experimental element to the API version 5.1.0.
I am removing an experimental element from the API. What version of the API should I give: 6.0.0, 5.1.1 or something else?


Not sure if there is an objective answer but I would tag it as 5.2.0. I'd consider only supported functionality (which experimental stuff IMHO isn't), so it is less than breaking, but it is affecting the API, so it is more than a bugfix.

semantic versioning also allows extensions to the version.. 5.1.0-dev 5.1.0+custom-5.2.0  lots of variations you can play with

@JeremyFiel do you think the major component of the version should not be incremented?

depends if it's a breaking change..  adding functionality to an existing service is not necessarily a breaking change. i was just giving examples of how you can use semantic version extensions.  there are tons of ways to use that and you can name those extensions whatever you want. build dev custom mynewthing and it doesn't need a full semantic version for the extension either  build-1 is sufficient -dev-1.2 is ok too

Hello @user85421. I want to remove an element - it is always a backwards incompatible change (if someone used it). But this element is marked as experimental (thus warning that it can be removed or changed at any time).

Arguably this is an opinion-based question but I will try to give my take on the subject.
If it is possible I would heavily suggest "hiding" experimental features behind some flag/header (like enableExperimentalFeatures) so user will need to explicitly "consent" on using those and verifies that all risks are understood (hence no compatibility guarantees are given). This will allow you to manipulate only the minor/patch versions and not to "litter" the version pool with major ones which do not actually have any major changes for stable API.
Alternatively you can ship two version, one with experimental suffix following the pre-release versioning handling suggested by the SemVer (i.e. you will ship X.Y.Z and X.Y.Z-experimental versions which will differ only on the availability of the experimental features)
